# How to inject a nested map.entries in Java?

Tags: spring, collections, dictionary

I am trying to get the value of the second entry and having isues. Thanks in advance for your help.

here is my code:

```
<util:map id="externalUrlMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry key="privacy">        
        <util:map map-class="java.util.HashMap">
            <entry key="en" value="${exit.privacy.url.en}"/>
            <entry key="fr" value="${exit.privacy.url.fr}"/>        
        </util:map>        
    </entry>
   <entry key="logout">        
        <util:map map-class="java.util.HashMap">
            <entry key="en" value="${exit.logout.url.en}"/>
            <entry key="fr" value="${exit.logout.url.fr}"/>        
        </util:map>        
    </entry>
</util:map>
```

and the controller

```
String urlType = "privacy";
    // Using Iterator to loop externalUrlMap
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Entry<String, String>>> entries = externalUrlMap.entrySet().iterator();  

    // Start Iterator 
    while (entries.hasNext()) {             
          Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry = entries.next();

          if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(urlType)){
              String key = entry.getKey();
              //Object value = entry.getValue().en; 
              List<String> list =  entry.getValue();
                //first item
                String first = list.get(0);
                //second item  
                 String second = list.get(1);

              System.out.println(key + "" + ""+ first +""+ second );
          }
    }
```

This is the error I get
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterator> to Iterator>>
Thanks a lot.

Comment: it the to analyse the problem with the map?

Comment: I am trying to pull out the value of the second entry. key="en" value="${exit.logout.url.en} and I cant figure out how to iterate through the values.

Comment: `externalUrlMap.get(urlType).get("en")` doesn't work?

Comment: what says the debugger, when inspecting externalUrlMap.

Comment: do the placesholder come from a properties file? if so, would't it be easier to access the properties object direct?

Comment: here is the output I get from the second entry: logout={en=http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/e-services/index.asp, fr=http://www.cic.gc.ca/francais/services-e/index.asp} now I want to get whats inside logout.

Comment: here is the entries output [logout={en=http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/e-services/index.asp, fr=http://www.cic.gc.ca/francais/services-e/index.asp}, privacy={en=http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/atip/index.asp, fr=http://www.cic.gc.ca/francais/ministere/airp/index.asp}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to test I did the following minimalistic setup. No problem to access the values direkt.

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("/application-context.xml");
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> externalUrlMap = (Map<String, Map<String, String>>)context.getBean("externalUrlMap");

        System.out.println(externalUrlMap.get("privacy").get("en"));
        System.out.println(externalUrlMap.get("privacy").get("fr"));
        System.out.println(externalUrlMap.get("logout").get("en"));
        System.out.println(externalUrlMap.get("logout").get("fr"));


    }
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd         
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd         
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<bean 
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

        <property name="location">
            <value>url.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <util:map id="externalUrlMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry key="privacy">        
        <util:map map-class="java.util.HashMap">
            <entry key="en" value="${exit.privacy.url.en}"/>
            <entry key="fr" value="${exit.privacy.url.fr}"/>        
        </util:map>        
    </entry>
   <entry key="logout">        
        <util:map map-class="java.util.HashMap">
            <entry key="en" value="${exit.logout.url.en}"/>
            <entry key="fr" value="${exit.logout.url.fr}"/>        
        </util:map>        
    </entry>
</util:map>

</beans>
```

Comment: I am testing this out. Thanks a lot. One question I guess I can use the @Resource to inject the map instead of GenericXmlApplicationContext. Right?

Comment: @Resource should work. May be you must also add @Qualifier("externalUrlMap").

Comment: resource worked without adding the @Qualifier("externalUrlMap"). Thanks again for your help.